# Is the Throwable returned from fillInStackTrace safe to downcast?

Tags: java, exception, casting

If I have `class MyException extends Exception`, then `myException.fillInStackTrace()` still returns `Throwable`, due to the way java's type system works. Is it safe to cast the return value to `MyException`?

Comment: Did you try?  If so what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to java sources:

```
/**
     * Fills in the execution stack trace. This method records within this
     * {@code Throwable} object information about the current state of
     * the stack frames for the current thread.
     *
     * <p>If the stack trace of this {@code Throwable} {@linkplain
     * Throwable#Throwable(String, Throwable, boolean, boolean) is not
     * writable}, calling this method has no effect.
     *
     * @return  a reference to this {@code Throwable} instance.
     * @see     java.lang.Throwable#printStackTrace()
     */
    public synchronized Throwable fillInStackTrace() {
        if (stackTrace != null ||
            backtrace != null /* Out of protocol state */ ) {
            fillInStackTrace(0);
            stackTrace = UNASSIGNED_STACK;
        }
        return this;
    }
```

That's why the answer is yes, it is safe to cast the return value to MyException, unless you haven't override `fillInStackTrace()` method in MyException class.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the implementation of myException.fillInStackTrace(). Sample implementation of fillInStacktrace()

```
protected static final MyException  ABORT = new MyException () {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1687848994976808490L;

        public Throwable fillInStackTrace() {
            return this;
        }
    };
```